# How to add C:\windows\system32 to path on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, command-line, cmd

Just checked my path ... noticed that `C:\windows\system32` was not present.

How can I add this to my path variable, since `setx` isn't a recognized command? I'm using Windows 8.1 Enterprise if that helps.

Comment: `setx` is part of Windows Server Management tools. Search the web for "Windows 8 set path", which will yield plenty of results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
PATH=%PATH%;c:\windows\system32
```

would work at the command line.  This will only change it until the command shell exists.

If you go to user accounts and your account I think there is edit environment variables on the left.  This will change it for all subsequent sessions.

Consider not changing it permenantly

Comment: Great. I'm guessing this code only changes it for the session it is in?